# Defining the h-topology via v-covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, grothendieck-topology

I have two questions about v-covers and the h-topology (as defined by Voevodsky) which arose when reading Bhatt-Scholze's "Projectivity of the Witt vector affine Grassmannian" available here https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06490

> > Question 1. In Definition 2.1 of Bhatt-Scholze's paper, a v-cover is defined by using valuation rings. Does it suffice to use discrete valuation rings in this definition?

> > Question 2. How does one show that the h-topology as defined by Bhatt-Scholze is the same as the h-topology defined by Voevodsky? I did not find a detailed proof of this in their paper (because it is presumably very simple...).

Comment: The answer to question 1 is no. For question 2, Bhatt and Scholze do not claim any thing being easy but rather explcitly rely on the beautiful paper by David Rydh, Submersions and effective descent of  ́etale morphisms. Bull. Soc. Math. France, 138(2):181–230, 2010 (freely available on NUMDAM), which very fine to read. This paper of Gabber and Kelly might be enlightening: arXiv:1407.5782 as well, at least to forge an intuition within noetherian schemes.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski Thank you for this. I will read the paper by Rydh, and also have a look at Gabber-Kelly. About question 1: I presume this is a standard argument. Is the answer to question 1 yes if one sticks to the realm of noetherian schemes and/or finitely presented morphisms?

Comment: You could also consult Bhatt-Mathew, *the arc-topology*: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.04725